# Clarification on Riemann Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

A comp exam problem asks us to prove "the following piece of the Riemann Mapping Theorem."

If $f,g$ are analytic bijections from an open set $A$ to the unit disc $D$ with $f(a) = g(a) = 0$ and $f'(a),g'(a)>0$ for some $a\in A,$ show that $f=g$ on $A$.

Unless there is some reason that $f'(a),g'(a)$ must be real numbers, it doesn't make sense to write $f'(a),g'(a)>0,$ so what is the correct statement? Beyond that, I have no idea how to begin to prove this. Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It's implicit in writing $f'(a) > 0$ that $f'(a)$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Bbb C$ is not an ordered field, but $w > 0$ is a frequently used short form for "$w$ is a positive real number".

You can prove the uniqueness of the Riemann mapping by applying the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) to 
both $h = g \circ f^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, I should have suspected as much. This is what I have from poking around: $h = g\circ f^{-1}$ would be a conformal map of the unit disc, so $h=\lambda\frac{z-b}{1-\bar{b}z}$ for some $|b|<1$, $|\lambda| = 1$. Then $h(0) = 0$ implies $b = 0$, and $\lambda = h'(0) = \frac{g'}{h'}(a)>0$ implies $\lambda = 1$, i.e. $g = f$. But can I ask why $f$ and $g$ are conformal?

Comment: @FrancisBegbie: An injective analytic function  *is* a conformal mapping.